# Sort initial array by average value

Tags: arrays, sorting

I'm trying to make a function that returns my initial arrays sorted by their average value.

For example I have this :

```
$array1 = [1,2,3];
$array2 = [1,1,1];
```

And this is a function that I made for returning the average of each array :

```
function average($a) {
    return (array_sum($a)/count($a));
}
```

I need to return the initial array sorted by their average like this or else

```
$x = [ $array2 , $array1 ];
```

Thank you.

Comment: What language is this? PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$multi_arr = [[1,2,3], [1,1,1]];
$avgs = [];

foreach ($multi_arr as $arr) {
   $avgs[] = average($arr);
}

// Keep index association
asort($avgs, SORT_NUMERIC);
// Get ordered array indexs
$keys = array_keys($avgs);
$sorted = [];
foreach ($keys as $index) {
    $sorted[] = $multi_arr[$index];
}
```